# How to align Bootstrap grids like a masonry layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

My grid setup now is as follows:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12'>
    <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-center'  style="height:200px;background-color:#0077CC; border-right:2px solid white; border-bottom: 2px solid white">
         DIV 1
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'style="height:320px;background-color:#0077CC; border-right:2px solid white; border-bottom: 2px solid white">
         DIV 2
    </div>

    <div class='col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-center' style="height:200px;background-color:#0077CC; border-right:2px solid white; border-bottom: 2px solid white">
         DIV 3
    </div>
</div>
```

My current output is
[image]

I want to get rid of the white space between div 1 and div 3. I don't want to merge div 1 and div3 because in mobile mode div 2 goes below div 3.

My expected outcome is
[image]

How can I achieve this in bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple: below is a demo for the same using bootstrap 4.
A grid must be wrapped inside a `container` and a `col` always inside a `row`.

```css
div {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          DIV 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-block d-md-none">
          DIV2 on small
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          DIV 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 d-none d-md-block">
      DIV 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFIDDLE link to play around with](http://jsfiddle.net/z0epvwn5/)

Comment: well, if I view this on a mobile device, div 2 will go below div3. I don't want that to happen. That's the main issue here.

Comment: In thats case you will have to add one more dive in between 1 and 3 and make it visible on small devices and hide on medium and large and vice versa with div 2. Make use use of display utilities

Comment: Thanks Manish. Let me try this now

Comment: It's probably becasue I'm using bootstrap 3 and display utilities are for bootstrap4

Comment: Ok so either you can write media queries for this to achieve... Or migrate to bootstrap 4... Or you can take only utilities from bootstrap 4 and use them.. what build system are you using.. and are you using css or SCSS?

Answer (score -2):

How about this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div>
            div 1
        </div>
        <div class="visible-xs">
            div 2
        </div>
        <div>
            div 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
        div 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rutmws7a/

Comment: If you're going to down vote me explain why, what I wrote works for what the question asks for. Still I'd appreciate constructive criticism.